# Ms Teams Channel: Drives are not fetching

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating Microsoft Team and channel under it using graph API.
Here is my code execution

```
/Groups  --Post
/groups/{groupid}/team  --Post
/teams/{groupid}/channels  --Post
```

But when I am trying to fetch the drives list under this group using

```
/groups/{groupid}/drive/root/children
```

it just returns the General channel drive.
It's not returning the newly created channel drive.
It was working as expected before as it was returning me drives for both the channels.
I used to put some dealy too and using re-try 5 times with 10 seconds delay.but no luck.
In my finding, I found that when I click on Files tab of this team then the endpoint

```
/groups/{groupid}/drive/root/children
```

also starts returning data for both the drives.

This problem just introduced today.

is there any change in API?
or is the and limit to create automatically drives for the channels??

Comment: Whenever a team or group is created a default folder will be generated within in sharepoint that will be accessible inside the files tab.I'm not sure why you are getting this error, Do you have all required permissions for the API?

Comment: yes  all permission are enabled.. this issue comes some time as its under development and i am creating many teams and channels..it looks like its some issue related to limit or delay..but I am not sure.

Comment: Could you please provide the request id so we can take a look?

Comment: as per my investigations, i found that site collection for the newly created channel is not getting provisioned. How I can provision a site for the newly created channel using graph api ?